# Facebook dictionary application

Tags: c#, facebook

I want to develop a Facebook app like a dictionary tool available in browser addons using .net. when an user selected a word, we have to show the meaning of that word. is it possible in c#?. somebody pls help me.

Comment: It is possible, but C# isn't the best tool for it. Also, I don't understand how this is a facebook app. Elaborate?

Comment: I want to develop this inside facebook itself. Because we dont need to add any additional addons in browsers

Comment: If you don't do this as a browser addon it will not work outside your Facebook Page tab.

Comment: I need like that only. I need to use it inside Facebook itself.

Comment: Yes, but this will only work on YOUR Facebook page, not any other Facebook page. To get the functionality you want, this has to be a browser addon of some sort.

Comment: Is there any possible to get the functionality if someone allow my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can convert C# code to [lingua franca](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingua_franca) of the web -- JavaScript with [Script#](http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp).

Comment: Can you Please explain how to implement this?